# ios app close after launch screen only if is launched manually from simulator xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm working on an ios app which is giving me problems because when I launch it manually from simulator it is closed after launch screen without log or error, this is happening in devices too. If I launch it from xcode with Cmd+D or R, all works fine.

Comment: Same problem here.